# Problem with nesting layouts

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, nested

I have a following situation in my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/topbar"
    >
    <TableRow >
        <TextView android:minWidth="280sp" 
            android:id="@+id/header" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/path_color"
            android:paddingLeft="10px"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <org.solid.explorer.HorizontalPager
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
    </org.solid.explorer.HorizontalPager>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contextMenu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >
            <org.solid.explorer.ContextOption
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                />
            <org.solid.explorer.ContextOption
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                />
            <org.solid.explorer.ContextOption
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                />
            <org.solid.explorer.ContextOption
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                />
            <org.solid.explorer.ContextOption
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drag_view"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/drag_icon"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/drag_label"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
<!--        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drag_icon1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
    /> -->
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is with the LinearLayout with id drag_view.

In program code, I am using ImageView with id drag_icon1 (it is being dragged by finger). Then everything is fine. But i want to add text to this icon so then I need to drag not the ImageView but the LinearLayout with ImageView and TextView inside, am I right?

But when I switch to the LinearLayout and comment the old ImageView (as in presented xml) the program fails at the setContentView method (second line of onCreate(), so further code has nothing common with this problem). WTF? If drag_icon1 is uncommented and used as dragged image then everything is fine, setContentView works (even with drag_view present).

Here is the stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(13517): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(13517): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.solid.explorer/org.solid.explorer.Explorer}:java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
E/AndroidRuntime(13517):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1816)
E/AndroidRuntime(13517):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1837)
E/AndroidRuntime(13517):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
E/AndroidRuntime(13517):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1033)
E/AndroidRuntime(13517):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(13517):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
E/AndroidRuntime(13517):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
E/AndroidRuntime(13517):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13517):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(13517):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime(13517):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime(13517):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13517): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
E/AndroidRuntime(13517):        at org.solid.explorer.Explorer.onCreate(Explorer.java:126)
E/AndroidRuntime(13517):        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
E/AndroidRuntime(13517):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1780)
E/AndroidRuntime(13517):        ... 11 more
```

It suggests that something wrong is with LayoutParams, but with drag_icon1 it works without problems.. I don't have any idea what is wrong.. Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the layout XML you posted is the complete file, the problems I see are:

- You need to have a single root element.
- You close a `LinearLayout` at the bottom of the document that I don't see.

However, if this is true, I'm not sure how you could get it to work by uncommenting the `ImageView`.

Comment: There is one root element but I didn't paste everything, sorry. On the top there is opening tag for LinearLayout so this is the root element.

Comment: Can you post your code?  There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the layout.  It loads fine for me.

Comment: You're right, there's nothing wrong with my xml. Simply I forgot to change one line to dragView instead of dragImage. Sorry :p